# searching for installed rpms by vendor

Tags: linux, rpm

I am trying to figure out the syntax to use to search installed rpms by a specific Vendor in Linux. I was ideally just trying to use the rpm -qi grepping for a specific vendor but that doesn't seem to work. Anyone have the syntax for this search?

Comment: I am looking for a way to query installed rpms that could have licensing associated with it - for example IBM or Oracle. What other approach could I take?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can show packages by vendor using a query format. I'd consider something like this, to list all packages:

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{vendor}:%{name}\n' | sort > packages.txt
```

You can then inspect the `packages.txt` file, which will look something like this, and will be sorted by vendor:

```
Codership Oy:galera
Fedora Project:certbot
Fedora Project:clang
Fedora Project:epel-release
...
(none):gpg-pubkey
(none):nginx
...
Red Hat, Inc.:acl
Red Hat, Inc.:aic94xx-firmware
...
Remi Collet:php-cli
Remi Collet:php-common
```

Or you can just `grep` instead if you know what you're looking for.

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{vendor}:%{name}\n' | grep 'Red Hat'
```

But querying the rpmdb takes some time, so it's faster to dump the whole thing to a file and then read or `grep` the file.

```
grep 'Red Hat' packages.txt
```

---

For extra bonus points, try the query format `'%{vendor}:%{name}:%{license}\n'` which will append the license information from each RPM.

```
Red Hat, Inc.:acl:GPLv2+
Red Hat, Inc.:aic94xx-firmware:Redistributable, no modification permitted
```